# javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, wildfly

I am working on a JSF project using PrimeFaces 6.0 and WildFly 8.2. Occasionally I recieve the following error:

```
03:58:59,238 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-14) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: at/bibliothek/web/NewCustomerBean$1
    at at.bibliothek.web.NewCustomerBean.saveNewCustomer(NewCustomerBean.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

......
```

The dollar sign at the end of

```
 at/bibliothek/web/NewCustomerBean$1
```

implies an inner class in the enclosing class NewCustomerBean. Indeed, at row 138

```
at.bibliothek.web.NewCustomerBean.saveNewCustomer(NewCustomerBean.java:138)
```

there stays a switch statement

```
switch (this.custmerType) {
```

where customerType is defined as an enumeration of type KundeType like this:

```
private KundeTyp custmerType;
```

Now, KundeTyp has long time been an inner class (an inner enumeration), however I already changed it, and now it is a "normal" enumeration in its own class

```
public enum KundeTyp {
```

in the same package. Could somebody tell me the reason for this exception then?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you try adding a `main` method to the bean which would create an instance and set its customerType to something? Then run in in your IDE as a standalone Java application. Just to check that it works outside WildFly. Then I would try a complete rebuild (like `mvn clean package`).

Comment: Thank you for your idea and contribution! Actually, I "solved" the problem by cleaning all temporary folders of WildFly and deploying anew - apparently, the problem was somewehre in these temporary folders of WildFly. Now it works.